# Retrieve dynamic values from Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

### Objective

To retrieve values from Excel sheet that is changing each second.

### Efforts so far

1. Created shared excel file so that it can be retrieved by more than two processes simultaneously.
2. Tried to read excel file that is receiving updates from RTD Server. The file is changing cells values each second. I read it by using *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel*
3. Simultaneously accessing data from excel file into GridView using *System.Data.OleDb*.

### Looking for

How to read those dynamic values from excel sheet? Because until those values are not saved, I can't read them from code they way I am doing now.

*I believe that there should be way for accessing those changing values in cells. But I am not gettig any hint.*

Comment: maybe this would help. Or at least guide you a different path. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181820/display-old-and-new-values-for-a-cell)

Comment: Can you change your first process to increment rows on each change so it acts more like a data logger?

Comment: I found solution but didn't implemented it. The solution was to make Excel behave as RTD Server and then make application as RTD client. **Because Excel can behave both as RTD Server and RTD Client**.